# How would a city work to accommodate much larger and smaller humanoids?

Tags: architecture, interspecies-relations, urban-fantasy

In my story there's a rather highly populated city with multiple humanoid creatures with varying heights. I'm not sure how much this would matter, but the most common species in the city are humans and the least common would be giants. Goblins (4ft) and gnomes are in the middle of the spectrum, along with elves who are about the same height as humans. I was thinking that because giants are uncommon only smaller parts of the city would accommodate them. But this would mean that entire sections would be incredibly hard for them to navigate, but I suppose this might not matter as much.
My biggest problem was figuring out how creatures with higher populations such as goblins and gnomes would live in the city. I was thinking maybe little underground roads or pathways under the city for gnomes to travel in (to avoid being bumped by humans), and maybe tightropes that span across the city for goblins to climb on. But this makes me wonder how even simple stuff would work such as how a restaurant would be laid out to accommodate everyone, or even how public restrooms, hotels/apartments, a town hall, and work buildings would be laid out.

Comment: This has been done a couple of times already. https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/30228/how-does-one-design-a-city-meant-for-creatures-of-greatly-varying-sizes https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/9507/what-should-architecture-of-an-imperial-capital-be-like-in-order-to-accommodate, I vaguely remember there might be more versions.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will have a look at them.

Answer (score 1):

You could have different district like sections for each and have public buildings being adapted for all species by including ropes, little roads and giant adaptation in percentage to the population ratio of each.

Comment: Zootopia is a great example of how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

If 'smaller' is the size of human children from around the [age of 7](https://af.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groei#/media/L%C3%AAer:Male_Stature_vs_Age.svg), try thinking of it that way. Children of that age can navigate cities almost as well as adult humans (depending on their means of transportation, but since you don't mention vehicles, I assume they mostly travel by foot, and even by equine would not pose a much larger problem). They can share pavements and most urban roads (depending - again - on transportation methods).

Establishments will have dedicated furniture, or even just adjustable furniture in the less adapted ones (which will likely be a major cause for patronization, but that might prove an interesting subject to tackle in your story :).
The more respectable establishments will have staff of all species, or at least one for each 'height category': elves and humans can serve either, as can gnomes and goblins.
Doors will often need smaller insetted doors. Windows will generally start at lower heights.
Taverns offer native dishes to those races they serve regularly. Prices are dependent on plate size.

If tightropes or the more comfortable [hanging bridges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_suspension_bridge) are used, establishments can have their higher floors dedicated to the smaller species. [Segregation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racial_segregation) is always a risk you need to take into account, though.

Major routes throughout the city can be giant-friendly. Popular establishments and services along these routes can have dedicated areas for their taller patrons. Take into consideration the amount of goods this takes, to, for example, stock taverns that serve giants.
Around the edges of the city there will likely be more space for mixed-race businesses. Most giants might not want to travel into a crowded city anyway.

If all species have their own language, and don't necessarily speak a common tongue, signage needs to address this.